# Edit smali file

Tags: android, smali

I have a smali code that I want to add a log to. As I have no knowledge in smali, I need your help.

The original Java code is:

```
    static HttpURLConnection createHttpURLConnection(String linkURL) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(linkURL).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", HTTP.IDENTITY_CODING);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            return urlConnection;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("URLConnection exception", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I result smali code looks like this:

```
.method static createHttpURLConnection(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
    .locals 5
    .param p0, "linkURL"    # Ljava/lang/String;

    .prologue
    .line 64
    :try_start_0
    new-instance v1, Ljava/net/URL;

    invoke-direct {v1, p0}, Ljava/net/URL;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 65
    .local v1, "url":Ljava/net/URL;
    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/net/URL;->openConnection()Ljava/net/URLConnection;

    move-result-object v2

    check-cast v2, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;

    .line 67
    .local v2, "urlConnection":Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
    const-string/jumbo v3, "Accept-Encoding"

    const-string/jumbo v4, "identity"

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3, v4}, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;->setRequestProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 68
    const/4 v3, 0x1

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;->setDoInput(Z)V
    :try_end_0
    .catch Ljava/lang/Exception; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

    .line 74
    .end local v1    # "url":Ljava/net/URL;
    .end local v2    # "urlConnection":Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
    :goto_0
    return-object v2

    .line 69
    :catch_0
    move-exception v0

    .line 70
    .local v0, "e":Ljava/lang/Exception;
    const-string/jumbo v3, "URLConnection exception"

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/Exception;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v4

    invoke-static {v3, v4}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 71
    const/4 v2, 0x0

    goto :goto_0
.end method
```

I want to add this line (Shown in Java):

```
Log.e("creating new connection to", linkURL);
```

as the first line in the function, inside the `try`

How would it look like in the smali code?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend creating a basic "Hello World!" type app, and then adding your target line of java code (or similar) into that app, and then disassemble it to see what the smali looks like, and then trying to understand the smali code, to better learn it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the smali code with your log added in the first line of try block. You can also use [java2smali](https://java2smali.com/) online tool for converting java code to smali.

```
.method static createHttpURLConnection(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
    .locals 5
    .param p0, "linkURL"    # Ljava/lang/String;

    .prologue
    .line 64
    :try_start_0
    const-string v0, "creating new connection to"

    invoke-static {v0, p0}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    new-instance v1, Ljava/net/URL;

    invoke-direct {v1, p0}, Ljava/net/URL;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 65
    .local v1, "url":Ljava/net/URL;
    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/net/URL;->openConnection()Ljava/net/URLConnection;

    move-result-object v2

    check-cast v2, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;

    .line 67
    .local v2, "urlConnection":Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
    const-string/jumbo v3, "Accept-Encoding"

    const-string/jumbo v4, "identity"

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3, v4}, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;->setRequestProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 68
    const/4 v3, 0x1

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;->setDoInput(Z)V
    :try_end_0
    .catch Ljava/lang/Exception; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

    .line 74
    .end local v1    # "url":Ljava/net/URL;
    .end local v2    # "urlConnection":Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
    :goto_0
    return-object v2

    .line 69
    :catch_0
    move-exception v0

    .line 70
    .local v0, "e":Ljava/lang/Exception;
    const-string/jumbo v3, "URLConnection exception"

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/Exception;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v4

    invoke-static {v3, v4}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 71
    const/4 v2, 0x0

    goto :goto_0
.end method
```